# SAP CAP Fiori Elements Worklist Floorplan - How to persist a user variant

Tags: variant, sap-fiori, cap

I am creating a very simple CAP application using a standard Fiori Elements worklist UI.  By default, the user variant option is displayed allowing the user to control the layout of the table columns etc.  This is set by default for ODATA v  via a variable in the manifest.json file (e.g. "variantManagement": "Page")

The variant works fine and is 'saved' when i create a new one.  What is not clear to me, how do I implement being able to persist the user created variant so when the user logs on again (or after refresh of the browser) they can retrieve their variants.  At the moment, these disappear as they are only available during the specific session.